# Prestodb cassandraType is null error

Tags: cassandra, presto

I get this error when querying table in cassandra where there is date column. There is already open question in their git but no answer.

> Error running command: Error starting query at
>   http://localhost:8080/v1/statement returned an invalid response:
>   JsonResponse{statusCode=500, statusMessage=Internal Server Error,
>   headers={content-length=[7326], content-type=[text/plain], date=[Wed,
>   11 Apr 2018 15:36:41 GMT]}, hasValue=false} [Error:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: cassandraType is null

Comment: Just found out that it is not supported currently.

Comment: And what's annoying is that I'm googling this 7 months later and such a basic feature is still not yet supported. I hope it get's picked up sometime soon.

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra `date` type is supported since Presto 304.

Also, Presto was fixed not to throw `NullPointerException: cassandraType is null` when there is an unsupported data type.

Answer (score 1):

yes, It seems that the type date is not supported yet by cassandra connector. Here is the pull request for adding support for it:
https://github.com/prestodb/presto/pull/7123